# Excel Interop stopped working after upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11

Tags: excel-interop

I have this app which work perfectly under Windows 10 but has now stopped working on machines which have been upgraded from Windows 10. I have found out that the app works on 'pure' Windows 11 machines (i.e Machines which were created using Windows 11). I created a very simple test app  in c# to simply create an excel spreadsheet and show it:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();
            Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
            excelApplication.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

On Windows 10 machines and 'pure' Windows 11 machines it works. However on upgraded Windows 11 machines, I am getting the exception:

Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155).

I've tried to Repair Microsoft 356 but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Any suggestions?